# ClickTale and ClickTaleExec

Tags: javascript, jquery, clicktale

[Here](http://wiki.clicktale.com/Article/JavaScript_integration) i've found how to implement ClickTale for DHTML pages, and now i need to do so ClickTale execute this code

```
item.next().css('display', 'none');
item.css('background', '#D6E9D6');
```

the problem - i dont know how to write right a function which will run this code so i am planning to use ClickTale like this:

```
if(typeof ClickTaleExec=='function') {
    ClickTaleExec("item.next().css('display', 'none');");
    ClickTaleExec("item.css('background', '#D6E9D6');");
}
```

And i have a question is it correct? Logically will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked myself, no, it will not work.

But this

```
if(typeof ClickTaleExec=='function') {
    ClickTaleExec("$('#" + aItems[iCount].id + "').next().css('display', 'none');");
    ClickTaleExec("$('#" + aItems[iCount].id + "').css('background', '#D6E9D6');");
}
```

Works fine! :)